# Pass editable h2 element value to form textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, textarea

I have an **H2 element**: `<h2 contenteditable="true" class="input">This is a text</h2>`

And I have **textarea element**: `<textarea class="output">This is another</textarea>`

Now the **H2 element** is editable as you see and i want his content (what ever the user will type) to **update the input element value** live.

How can i? *(using javascript)*

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jquery you could use the following jsfiddle

`jquery`https://jsfiddle.net/kd9jLcs6/1/

Which uses the keyup function to update the h2's innertext with that of the text area

Comment: Thanks, But i need a non-jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need pure **JavaScript** solution just use [**HTMLElement: input event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) which states:

> The event also applies to elements with `contenteditable` enabled, and to any element when `designMode` is turned on. In the case of `contenteditable` and `designMode`, the event target is the editing host. If these properties apply to multiple elements, the editing host is the nearest ancestor element whose parent isn't editable.

As your `h2` element has `contenteditable` attribute with the value `true`, it should work.

Try the following:

```js
const h2 = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0];
const textarea = document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0];
h2.addEventListener('input', e => textarea.value = e.target.innerHTML);
```

```html
<h2 contenteditable="true" class="input">This is a text</h2>
<textarea class="output">This is another</textarea>
```

I hope this helps!